# What effect does <blockquote> have?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I know that, typically, text in `<blockquote> ... </blockquote>` tags will be rendered in a way that is slightly set off from the surrounding text, and with expanded margins on both sides. And, of course, may be styled differently.

> This text is probably appears within `<blockquote> ... </blockquote>` tags.

However, [modern guidelines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-WCAG20-HTML-TECHS-20050630/#blockquote_misuse) seem to be that this tag should not be used for this effect:

> Only use blockquote to indicate a quotation. Do not use it to create an indented effect on the page. blockquote is a semantic element and using it improperly can confuse the user.

This prompts the question: what *effects* does this tag *actually have* that would lead to confusion and thus require the aforementioned visual effect to be achieved through other means?

(I'm interested both in answers for what we have today, and what we might have in the future if everybody followed the guidelines)

Comment: Screen readers?

Comment: Looks like a good and a valid question. I don't see why indenting the `<blockquote>` elements would confuse the user when it is a common pattern in printed materials also.

Comment: @subwaymatch because printed/visible text is not the only medium for the web (html)? See: screen readers and visually impaired users.

Comment: @zerkms I was a little confused by the w3's working draft, but @jim-deville's answer cleared my confusion. Using indents for `<blockquote>` elements should be fine as long as the element is reinforcing the semantics. It shouldn't be used just for the effect when the content has nothing to do with citations or quotes.

Comment: @subwaymatch if it's addressing semantics then it does not matter how it's visually represented: with margins or blinking or hidden entirely. Semantics and visual representations are done separately.

Answer (score 2):

The point here is that you shouldn't use `<blockquote>` as a way just to get that effect unless you are using it to mark text that actually is a blockquote. Otherwise, it can confuse screen readers, and other tools that use the semantic information of elements to infer meaning.

If you want to have that effect, but just for a random piece of text, the guidance is to use a div and style it instead.

Comment: Nice answer. The w3 working draft should include this detail so that the readers of the draft are not confused.

Comment: I've seen this stated in the abstract, but *only* in the abstract. I want something concrete! Tricking a screen reader into saying the word "blockquote" before reading it doesn't strike me as particularly confusing, and my own google searches at to the effect only turn up banal things like that.

Comment: @Hurkyl "doesn't strike me as particularly confusing" --- sure, when you hear "a quote following" then you hear something that definitely is not a quote it's not confusing at all, right.

Comment: @Hurkyl I bet if you can get the millions of screen reader users who rely on it to agree with you, then we could get that guidance changed, until then, I'm pretty sure this guidance is based on empirical data

Comment: I guess I'm used to abstract visuals where the meaning is learned from usage rather than what the visual *actually* is, and don't have a feel for whether that  is a more jarring effect for audials. I still think some detail in the answer would be good if this really is a big effect.

Comment: Fair... I don't have that detail unfortunately